# Can't set width of a div

Tags: css, html, width

I've got a CSS conflict that's preventing me to set the width of a div and I'm really struggling to see where it is.

Can someone give me a hand?

It's this div here:

```
body.node-type-campaign #com_col_two {
width: 400px;
padding: 0;
border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

A link to the page: http://www.wdm.org.uk/test-campaign

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the inline-style `width:auto;` from `<div id="com_col_two">`

Comment: Indeed, specificity will always conquer.

Comment: That's so obvious! Thank you. *Hangs head in shame* :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just:

```
#com_col_two {
width: 400px;
padding: 0;
border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

And remove all the added properties on the `<div>` tag?

You have a lot of classes applied to the elements in your page.

Also, have you tried using Firefox with Firebug. I'm sure a lot of people would recommend using that.

Comment: Yes, I use that, thanks. The extra classes are unfortunately added by Drupal. Really annoying but that's life.

Answer (score 0):

Check out FF's Web Developer Toolbar or Chrome's Developer Tools: both have a CSS view which shows you *which* style definition affects *this* specific element (it is triggered by rightclick->Inspect element).